# Django Testing - loading data into the database before loading the apps

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-tests

I'm currently writting some tests for a Django app (+ REST framework), and having some issues loading the test data into the database.

Let me explain with some (very simplified) code :

I have a django view which is something like :

*view.py*

```
from myapp.models import Item
from myapp.utils import MyClass

# need to initialize with the set of items
item_set = {item.name for item in Item.objects.all()}
my_class_object = MyClass(item_set)

class MyView(APIView):
    def post(selfself, request):
        result = my_class_object.process(request.data)
        return Response(result)
```

So basically I need to initialize a class with some data from the database, and I then use this class in my view to process the data received by the endpoint.

Now the test :

*my_test.py*

```
from rest_framework.test import APILiveServerTestCase
from myapp.models import Item

class MyTest(APILiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.URL = '/some_url_linking_to_myview/'

        # load some data
        Item.objects.create(name="first item")
        Item.objects.create(name="second item")

    def test_myview_return_correct_result(self):
        post_data = {"foo"}
        response = self.client.post(self.URL,
                                    data=post_data,
                                    format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, {"my_expected_result"})
```

When running the test, what currently happens is that *view.py* is loaded before the *setUp()* method get excecuted, so when I instantiate the class with these two lines :

```
item_set = {item.name for item in Item.objects.all()}
my_class_object = MyClass(item_set)
```

the database is still empty.

I'm wondering if there is a way to either get the data into the database before *view.py* get executed, or maybe somehow force reloading the app after setUp(), or instantiate my class somewhere else so it gets called after loading the data ?

thanks !

Comment: This is a good demonstration of why you shouldn't put db-accessing code at module level.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`setUpTestData()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData).

Here is roughly how I set this up if I am going to use a significant amount of data:

**tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .tests.test_data import base_data

class MyClassTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        base_data.base_data(cls)
```

**base_data.py**

```
from .models import MyClass

def base_data(cls):
    cls.MyClass1 = MyClass.objects.create(
       name="first_name"
    )
    cls.MyClass2 = MyClass.objects.create(
       name="second_name"
    )
```

Of course, you can do everything directly in the `setUpTestData()` function, if you would rather have your test data sitting up top.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your answer. Unfortunately using setUpTestData doesn't help here (the database is still populated after instantiating my class). So my issue is basically that I'm accessing the database when the modules are compiled, which all occur before the test database is set up !

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the initiate code in the function and call from inside the post.

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def initialize(self):
        item_set = {item.name for item in Item.objects.all()}
        my_class_object = MyClass(item_set)

    def post(self, request):
        self.initialize()
        result = my_class_object.process(request.data)
        return Response(result)
```

`Edit 1`
Optionally, you can use fixture to load MyClass objects in the database beforehand

```
class MyTest(APILiveServerTestCase):
    fixtures = [
        // my class objects fixtures file
    ]
    def setUp():
        // rest of the code
```

Comment: That would work but would be too slow since it would instantiate the class for each call (querying all the items and instantiating the class is quite a expensive operation here that I really want to do just once). Although we could maybe combine this with some caching strategy..

Comment: If the code is only for testing then you can instantiate that in setUp.
However, for production, instantiating class globally is not a good practice

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I tried using a fixture but same problem: the database is populated only after instantiating the class. I might try your first approach with a boolean attribute to ensure we instantiate the class only on the first call to the view. But still looking to the 'proper' way to handle that kind of thing in django :)